# Erro idHTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: delphi

Bom dia,
  Já teste várias dicas e soluções sobre esse assunto aqui no forum e fora também, estou há 5 dias tentando realizando um post utilizando o idHttp com o delphi Berlin.

Esse é meu código;

```
procedure TfrmPlaPSync.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestBody: TStream;
  ResponseBody: string;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    try
      RequestBody := TStringStream.Create('{"cod_regiao": "41", "nome": "NORTE"}',TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
        HTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
        HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
        HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
        HTTP.Request.Username := 'robinho';
        HTTP.Request.Password := 'rb823321';
        HTTP.Request.Connection  := 'keep-alive';
        HTTP.Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36';
        HTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
        HTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
        HTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';

        ResponseBody := HTTP.Post('http://localhost:888/api/millenium/regioes/inclui',
          RequestBody);
        Memo2.Lines.Add(ResponseBody);
        Memo2.Lines.Add(HTTP.ResponseText);
      finally
        RequestBody.Free;
      end;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        Memo2.Lines.Add(E.Message);
        Memo2.Lines.Add(E.ErrorMessage);
      end;
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Memo2.Lines.Add(E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
end;
```

a API solicita uma autenticação básica que estou passando no header, porém estou tendo o seguindo erro:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: Por algum motivo o servidor está rejeitando suas credenciais, ou o usuário é autenticado mas não tem permissão pra página pra qual você faz o post. Eu sugiro usar um programa como o *Fiddler* ou o *Wireshark* pra ver como a aplicação Delphi está montando o cabeçalho da aplicação.

Comment: P.s.: aqui não é um fórum.

Comment: Boa tarde, descobri que o problema era na API que não aceitava a autenticação.

P.s: Desculpa, mas achei que era forum, pois vejo varias perguntas até mesmo desse erro.

Comment: Não é um fórum, é um site de perguntas e respostas. Há uma grande diferença. Veja o tour: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e depois uma olhada geral na Central de ajuda.

Comment: peço desculpas novamente, assim como eu tem vários que estão errados.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, 
Creio que o que esteja faltando seja o seguinte:

```
IdHTTP.Request.Clear;
IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Basic ' + seu_token_autorizacao);
```

Veja somente o nome do header e adapte para sua necessidade.
Pra mim, funcionou.

Abraço!